# A convex polyhedron has $f_n$ faces with $n$ edges and $v_n$ vertices at which $n$ edges meet.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra

This problem is from "Notes on Geometry" by E. Rees.

> A convex polyhedron has $f_n$ faces with $n$ edges and $v_n$ vertices at which $n$ edges meet.
>
> Show that
>
> - $\sum nf_n=\sum nv_n$
> - $\sum f_{2n+1}$ is even
> - $v_3+f_3 >0$

I would like to get some help with this problem. I am trying to use Euler's Formula (i.e. $V+F-E=2$).

What I can imagine is separating all faces and counting the edges of each polygon will give us $\sum nf_n$. And the total count of vertices of each polygon is $\sum nv_n$. But, I wonder if this is a general fact for any convex polyhedron. If this is right, then $E=\frac{\sum nf_n}{2}$ as edges overlap as a pair. And, we can rewrite the formula as $\sum f_n + \sum v_n - \frac{\sum nf_n}{2}=2$. This is because $F=\sum f_n$, $V= \sum v_n$.

Is this the right approach?

Any kind of help would be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is the correct one.

The first bullet point is thus proved with each sum equalling $2E$.

HINTS

Consider the equation  $\sum nf_n \equiv 2E $ modulo $2$.

If $v_3+f_3 =0$ then $\sum nv_n \ge 4V$ and so $2E\ge V$......

Comment: I appreciate it! I could show the first one, but I'm still stuck on the second one. May I ask how to show the second one with your hints?

Comment: Mod 2 you can ignore all $nf_n$ where $n$ is even. Furthermore, each  $nf_n$ with $n$ odd is the same as  $f_n$. The LHS of the equation therefore simply adds all $f_n$ with $n$ odd.